# xp_sendmail using table variable as @query SQL Server 2000

Tags: sql, email, sql-server-2000

I am trying to send a resultset via email using `xp_sendmail`.
I need to send the email when an earlier executed query has any results.

Got the query results into a table variable/temp table and then
in xp_sendmail, using

```
Declare @table_var table(...)

..query execution..

EXEC master.dbo.xp_sendmail @recipients = 'xx@xx.com', 
@query = 'select * from @table_var'
```

it gives error saying that

> @table_var must be declared.

Even if I use temporary table, the message I get is

> cannot reference object in tempdb database.

Any ideas on this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to use a real table for this.  Try..

```
 If exists (select * from sys.tables where name = 'mytable')
      drop table mytable
    Create Table mytable table(...)


    ..query execution..

    EXEC master.dbo.xp_sendmail @recipients = 'xx@xx.com', 
    @query = 'select * from mydatabase.dbo.mytable'
```